# Joining environment variables in Jenkins pipeline / groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to set a couple of environment variables in a Jenkinsfile, but my lack of Java/Groovy-ness seems to be failing me...

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        TMPDIR = /mnt/storage/build
        TOX_DIR = $TMPDIR/$BUILD_TAG
    }
...
```

Generates the following error on the console...

```
WorkflowScript: 7: Environment variable values can only be joined together with +s. @ line 7, column 26.
       TOX_DIR = $TMPDIR/$BUILD_TAG
```

Other variations such as ...

```
TOX_DIR = "$TMPDIR" + "/" + "$BUILD_TAG"
```

or

```
TOX_DIR = "$TMPDIR/$BUILD_TAG"
```

or

```
TOX_DIR = "${TMPDIR}/${BUILD_TAG}"
```

only make matters worse.

What am I missng?     Thanks....

Answer (score 22):

Using Jenkins v2.89.2 - Instead of using single quotes, double quotes worked for me.

```
environment{
    MESSAGE = "release-staging-${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

nm... answer is saner than I thought, just missing quotes...

```
....
environment {
    TMPDIR = '/mnt/storage/work'
    TOX_DIR = '${TMPDIR}/${BUILD_TAG}'
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Error `Environment variable values can only be joined together with ‘+’s` means that you *missed quotes*. just wrap quotes on string or string builder.

```
environment {
    SOME_VAR = "Content"
}
```